# REST API Request with JSON Parameters

Tags: json, rest, api

I am new to REST APIs and JSON and I've got a beginner question. The API that I am trying to use is asking for parameters according to the following schema:

```
<GetAppts xmlns="<Removed>" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:urn1="<Removed>">
<!--idtype occurs:0,1-->
<Patient xsi:nil="false">
<!--string occurs:0,1-->
<urn1:ID xsi:nil="false">Z42991</urn1:ID>
<!--string occurs:0,1-->
<urn1:Type xsi:nil="false">External</urn1:Type>
</Patient>
</GetAppts>
```

Example request parameters would be:

```
{"Patient":{"ID":"E1234","Type":"MRN"}}
```

However, when I am attempting to use SoapUI and Postman to test this API, I only see Key-Value pairs for the parameters, and I have no idea how to nest the ID and Type inside a Patient Object:

[SoapUI Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgxBb.png)

[Postman Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvE1y.png)

Comment: Hi caburse. Could you be more specific on how to do this exactly?

Comment: In postman try switching to body raw and you can add the json text

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the Json Text. Click Body then the raw radio button.
[image: Post Man]